# Microsoft Outlook 2007 freezes

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

What are the causes that MS Outlook 2007 freezes? It's OK a few seconds after launching the application but when I want to do some action (e.g. write new e-mail) it suddenly freezes.
Is there some troubleshooting?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar issues.

This was mostly related to either Xobni running or anti-virus. Try disabling anything similar you might have installed and see if the problem re-occurs.

Aside from that, you could always upgrade to 2010, but that might be cost-prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

Recreating your .OST file should fix this issue.

Open Outlook>File>Data File Management>Data Files

Remove file name outlook.ost

Restart Outlook.

Comment: I must agree. I this is my first step when coming across a similar issue. It doesn't always fix the issue. However, it's solves majority of cases. It's quick and easy.

Answer (score -1):

After over 12 hrs of reading and following all the advise on forums all over the place, I finally ran across a post that mentioned I cloud control panel. Well yes I had it on my computer and yes I deleted it and ....All better.

I can't believe that I found a fix and it was that simple but for me ..It was. I had done the repair, I had run defrag, I had done everything I could and was just about to uninstall Outlook 2007 and re-install when , something told me to keep looking and when someone mentioned problems with I could and what it did to outlook..I took it off and somehow..everything started working properly